# Appending to a dictionary using a class swift

Tags: swift

How would I go about creating a simple appendage to a dictionary with a function related to a class?

The dictionary should be formatted like [String: (String, String)]

```
class Fruit {
        let name: String
        let description: String
        let price: Int
        var fruits: [Fruit] = [name: (description, price)]

        init(name: String, description: String, cost: Int) {
            self.name = name
            self.description = description
            self.price = price
        }
        func addFruit() {
            fruits.append(Fruit:)
    }

    }
```

Comment: Ryan, I see a few issues in your code: 1. in the class's initializer, you assign the function parameter `price` to the instance variable `price`, however the name of the function parameter is `cost`. 2. the name of the class is `Fruit` but the `fruits` array is declared with an item type of `Fruits`. 3. There appears to be an extraneous curly brace; are the `fruits` array and `addFruit` function supposed to be declared inside the class?

Comment: @Jacob I fixed the issues you listed and edited it however I'm really not sure how I actually get this to work. My only prior experience is list comprehension so this is a step up.

Comment: @jacob I think I've fixed what needs to be fixed in the class but how would I call the function. please and thanks <3

Comment: This is array of Fruit object, you can add fruit type object only var fruits: [Fruit] = [name: (description, price)] , but in your case you are adding something diff

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have declared an array (not a dictionary). To store a fruit in a dictionary of the structure you specified, try this:

```swift
var fruits: [String: (description: String, price: String)] = [:]

func addFruit() {
    fruits["Banana"] = (description: "A tropical fruit, price: "0.65")
}
```

The `fruits` variable is a dictionary with a key type of `String` and a value type of `(description: String, price: String)`, a tuple with two named `String` fields (note the names are optional).

Notice how the dictionary key and value tuple encapsulate all the properties of the the `Fruit` class. In fact, the `Fruit` class is not used here at all. Unless you plan to add some methods or computed properties to the `Fruit` class, using this dictionary structure, for your purposes, may be a better approach.

Unlike some other languages, not everything needs to be encapsulated in a class in Swift; for a simple fruit type with a few properties, a tuple might be sufficient. Swift provides many ways of encapsulating the same data.

For example, you could also use an array instead of a dictionary and add a name field to the tuple:

```swift
var fruits: [(name: String, description: String, price: String)] = []

func addFruit() {
    fruits.append( 
        (name: "Banana", description: "A tropical fruit", price: "0.65")
    )
}
```

Furthermore, you could declare this tuple as its own type for easier use:

```swift
typealias Fruit = (name: String, description: String, price: String)

var fruits: [Fruit]

...
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan this is simple way to do this.

```
class Fruit {
  let name: String
  let price: Double
  let description: String
  init(name: String, price: Double, description: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.price = price
    self.description = description
  }
}

class FruitFactory {
   var fruits: [Fruit] = []
}

var fruitfactoryObj = FruitFactory.init()

var fruitObj = Fruit.init(name: "apple", price: 0.65, description: "good for health")
fruitfactoryObj.fruits.append(fruitObj)
```

Also please use double instead Int `let price: Double`

```
print(fruitfactoryObj.fruits[0].name)
```

result should be apple :)